# How to add root second parent id to oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, connect-by

I have a child-parent table like this (0 means that it is the top item):

```
itemID | parentItemId
---------------------
     1 |            0
     2 |            0
     3 |            0
     4 |            1
     5 |            1
     6 |            2
     7 |            5
     8 |            7
     9 |            7
```

I want to add a new column that will be rootItemId according to this logic:

If it is a top item then `rootItemId = itemID`, else `rootItemId` will be item *under the root* (i.e. level - 2) itemID.

It will look like this:

```
itemID | parentItemId | rootItemId 
----------------------------------
     1 |            0 |          1
     2 |            0 |          2
     3 |            0 |          3
     4 |            1 |          4
     5 |            1 |          5
     6 |            2 |          6
     7 |            5 |          5
     8 |            7 |          5
     9 |            7 |          5
```

I can get this result using the following sql:

```
      select itemID, 
             parentItemId, 
             itemID as rootItemId 
        from ItemTable
       where itemID = 0

       union

      select itemID, 
             parentItemId, 
             connect_by_root parentItemId as rootItemId
        from ItemTable
        start with parentItemId in 
           (select itemID 
            from ItemTable 
            where parentItemId =0)
       connect by prior itemID  =  parentItemId
```

Is there a more **elegant** and **efficient** way to achieve the **same results**?

Thanks

Comment: Your query is fine.  I prefer recursive CTEs (because they are standard SQL).  They are available only in Oracle12C+ and I suspect they have the same performance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff fwiw, [recursive subquery factoring](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2077142) is available from 11gr2, although there were some enhancements in 12c